# Book about time series

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, time-series

I've just finished the inference classes of professor Philippe Rigollet on MIT OpenCourse (also available on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPZD_aij8H0&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60uVBMaoNERc6knT_MgPKS0)) and I would like to know if there is a good book on time series that I can study with this background. Besides that I'm a self-learner.

Remark: Any advice or other sources recommendation (videos, sites, online classes, etc.) are also very welcome.

Comment: [Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Forecasting-Springer-Texts-Statistics-dp-3319298526/dp/3319298526/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) by Brockwell and Davis seems like it might be good.